# How to add borders on Shopping cart page column header names

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cart, shopping-cart, checkout-page

I'm trying to add borders on the Shopping cart page column header name. Anyone advises me

[image: I need cart page to look]

Answer (score 1):

You can add the borders using below code, add this code in your less file:

```
 .cart.table-wrapper {
    .cart thead {
        tr {
            th.col {
                border: 1px solid orange;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can this code in your less file (*_cart.less*).
You can find the less file here (Template:Luma):
vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module

Find this code in *_cart_less* and extend it with "border"

```
.cart.table-wrapper {
        .cart-products-toolbar {
            + .cart {
                thead {
                    tr {
                        th.col {
                            padding-bottom: @indent__s;
                            padding-top: @indent__s;
                            border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After you have changed the less file, run this code via command line.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```